# Why after i transfer to mobile view the document updates?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to display how many items are in the cart. After the user adds an item to the cart I want to display how many items he has in the cart. There's the code to check if there's more than one item in the cart and then to display it :

`{this.state.inCart.length > 0 ? ( <div className="in-cart-e">{this.state.inCart.length}</div> ) : <div style={{'padding': '14px'}}></div>}`

but the document updates only after I add another item to the cart or after I transfer to mobile view there's the code to add the item to the cart array:

```
async firstCart(){
  await this.setState({ firstCart: !this.state.firstCart });
   if (this.state.firstCart) {
      this.state.inCart.push('firstCart');
  }else{
    if (this.state.inCart.length > 0) {
      var index = this.state.inCart.indexOf('firstCart');
      this.state.inCart.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I'm already using the code to check if there's an item in the cart to display but this div is hidden from the web view, its only displayed on phone view.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: because somewhere you are causing a render by changing a class or layout for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there was a recent change in React...you cannot use `await` on `setState` because it is an async function that does not return a promise. This will not allow you to wait for the update to the state itself.

`setState` does offer a callback if you need to do something right after the update:

```
this.setState({ firstCart: !this.state.firstCart }, function () {
  //... do stuff here after update
})
```

More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

---

You also have a few more issues to resolve.

Seems like you are trying to update the state manually: `this.state.inCart.push('firstCart')` && `this.state.inCart.splice(index, 1)` where splice is an array mutator.

That's a no-go in react. Every state update must go through `setState` so the component can update accordingly.

Comment: I tried what you said but it still happens. And I checked if the inCart array length is more than one and it is but it still didn't change.

Comment: @T.sagiv Well, you also have a few more issues to resolve. Seems like you are trying to update the state manually: `this.state.inCart.push('firstCart')`. That's a no-go in react. Every state update should use `setState` so the component can update accordingly.